# Android one time tutorial

Tags: java, android

I am trying to design an app and am really new to both coding and android development.

In my app, (a homework planner that uses SQLite Database), I want a screen to prop up once, the first time the app is launched, where the user enters a number of classes (such as math, english etc).
Anyone know how I can accomplish this? one of the main problems is how to have a screen that only runs the 1st time and then never again.

Thank you!

Comment: Store the fact that it has happened in shared preferences - or simply in the database existing and having a non-zero set of chosen class subjects.  You should probably provide a menu option somewhere for your user to get back to the configuration if they made a mistake or add/drop a class.

Comment: Rafa, you should do some googling before posting questions. Very few or new things are there in Android which have not been asked already. Would save you from negative votings.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) to store an attribute like 'firstTime'. 
The first time the application is opened, you could alter the value and check it everytime the app is opened.

Answer (score 0):

You can check your database, if the user entered a number of classes. If he dont, show this dialog, else not.

There are many other ways you could solve your problem!